# Showing a macOS service in the menu

Tags: macos, automation, services

I have written a simple Automator workflow which process selected text. It does the job, and is available from most applications in the Service menu in the Text group.

I have one application, the application I really wanted to use it for, which doesn’t show the text group in the Services menu, but it does show the development and general group.

Is there a technique to either show the Text group or to change the grouping of the workflow to the Development or General group?

Here is the workflow:

[image]

Comment: Do you have text selected? Even TextEdit shows no Text Services when there's no selection.

Comment: @benwiggy Yes, I have.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the Automator workflow? It should show in the Services menu if you've selected "Workflow receives Text in Any Application".

Comment: @benwiggy I’ve just added one …

Comment: Have you tried setting it for that particular application? If it works, then leave it for that application and create another for **in [any application]**. BTW I have found it to be inconsistent as to which menu item it will show under and I think is not controllable by the user beyond how it comes out. I'm saying that anecdotally after 15+ years of observation.

Comment: Did what I suggested in my previous comment work for you?

Comment: @user3439894 No, I tried that, and still no joy.

Comment: What is the name of the _application_ that you can't get this to work with?

Comment: @user3439894 Mu Editor https://codewith.mu/ . It’s not a deal breaker, but I have come across a few other applications in the past where not all services seem to be available, so I wondered whether there was a more general fix to this.